# continuous function using the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ an integrable function. Defines $g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t) dt$. Show that $g$ is continuous using the monotone convergence theorem.

I cannot find out the way of apply the monotone convergence theorem there, how can I define an increasing sequence related to $g$?

I'll appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: g(x) is an increasing function

Comment: I still cannot find out how to use the theorem. Since $g$ is increasing, I could consider the sequence $(x_n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ with $x_n\longrightarrow x_0$ and try to prove that $g(x_n)\longrightarrow g(x_0)$. Then by the theorem $\lim\int g(x_n) d\mu = \int\lim g(x_n) d\mu$, but I'm not able to go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the classical monotone convergence theorem to show that $g$ is continuous from the left: if $x_n\uparrow x$, then define $f_n(t):=f(t)\chi_{(-\infty,x_n)}$, which pointwise increases to $t\mapsto f(t)\chi_{(-\infty,x)}$. In order to check the continuity from the right, we use this version of monotone convergence theorem:

> If $(h_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a pointwise non-increasing sequence of measurable non-negative functions on a measure space $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$, i.e. $h_n(x)\downarrow h(x)$ for any $x$, and $h_0$ is integrable, then 
>   $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_X h_n(x)\mathrm d\mu(x)=\int_X h(x)\mathrm{d}\mu(x).$$
>   This can be deduced using the classical MCT with $h_0-h_n$.

Comment: Excuse me but I can't figure out how to use the theorem in order to prove de continuity of g from the letf. Can you be more especific? I may be able to do it from the right if you especify me hw to do it from the left. Thank you

Comment: @Davide Giraudo just coming across this, a few years later. I believe that silently you are using that is sufficient to check left and right sequential continuity on monotone sequences, correct?

Comment: @Mr_3_7 Yes (but not so silently).

Comment: @Davide Giraudo. Indeed. As a byproduct of this discussion I can now show that every bounded sequence whose limit coincides with the sup (inf) has an increasing (decreasing) reordering, I didn't know that- thanks